# Sort array of strings with Polish characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have a problem with sorting an array which have strings with special Polish characters. My code looks like this:

```
 ["Łotwa", "Luksemburg", "Anglia"].sort_by{|x| ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate(x)}
```

and this code gives me the following result:

```
["Anglia", "Łotwa", "Luksemburg"]
```

but it should look like this:

```
["Anglia", "Luksemburg", "Łotwa"]
```

I tried to use these gems:

```
https://github.com/grosser/sort_alphabetical
https://github.com/jarib/ffi-icu
```

but they do not solve this problem. Problem is caused by the special Polish character `"Ł"`.

Comment: Depending on what and where you are doing this sorting, one approach could be to use the collation support of your DB instead of doing it in Ruby.

Comment: I guess you should make your question more clear - i.e. to let others know that `'Ł'` should be between `'L'` and `'M'`, for example. Otherwise, this question is quite misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [string_case_pl](https://github.com/apohllo/string_pl) gem:

```
require 'string_cmp_pl'
%w(Anglia Litwa Zanzibar Łotwa).sort
# => ["Anglia", "Litwa", "Łotwa", "Zanzibar"]
```